# Imported model from Steam version of Fuse has flipped faces when rendered. Flipping normals does not work

Tags: export, import, normals

The title mostly describes the issue I have with Blender 2.8. When exporting the model from the Steam version of Fuse, I export it as a .OBJ file and box appears with multiple options:

- Export in new folder
- Flip Normals
- Combine diffuse (RBG) and Specular (A)
- Remove occluded polygons
- Pack textures and UVs

I only have "export in new folder" and "remove occluded polygons" selected. I have tried selecting "flip normals" and deselecting "remove occluded polygons" in separate exports, however, both options did not make a difference to the result. As the title says, I have also tried flipping normals by selecting all the faces of the model and using the hotkey "SHIFT + CTRL + N" which did nothing.

I have included multiple images showing what the model looks like in both edit and render mode in Blender as well what the model looks like in Fuse.

[image: Soldier model in edit view/mode in Blender]

[image: Soldier model in edit mode]

[image: Soldier model with flipped faces when rendered]

[image: What the soldier model is supposed to look like]

Thanks in advance. If you require any additional information such as settings, please let me know! I am not very experienced with Blender so you may need to help me navigate to show you the settings you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was quite simple and if I did a bit more research and watched a video, this would have been simple. All I had to do was to select the model, select materials, scroll down to settings and change "Blend Mode" to "Alpha Hashed." This has to be applied to all textures.